# How can I compile MDX2 to static HTML with components

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, transformation, mdxjs

I'm trying to write an MDX2-to-HTML compiler.  I've got most of it working (that is, I can compile a simple `.mdx` file to HTML), but without importable components.

I have read through the entire [MDX2 website](https://mdxjs.com/), but it's not quite clicking for me. I have a bunch of successful experiments that do various parts, but I haven't quite seen the whole yet.

### The Objective

I want to compile a set of MDX2 strings (one main fragment and a set of components) into a static HTML component-- *preferrably without accessing the disk*.

(This is not an absolute requirement, but I want to run it in an AWS lambda, and I won't have access to all the files at deployment time.  I could use the `/tmp` dir of the lambda, but would rather not for various reasons.)

### What I've Tried

Here's what I have so far.  **This works; it compiles MDX2 to HTML without touching the disk** (aside from loading the entrypoint in this example, but it could just as easily be a string from elsewhere).  But it doesn't let me do things like import MDX components, and it feels really dirty with the string manipulation I'm doing.

First, my `.mdx` file:

`//example.mdx`

```markdown
# Title

export const Thing = ({foo}) => <>{foo}</>

# Hello, <Thing foo="bar"/>!

This is the content.
```

Then I have a `.js` file:

```js
// example.js
import fs from 'node:fs/promises'
import { compile } from '@mdx-js/mdx'
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import {Fragment as _Fragment, jsx as _jsx, jsxs as _jsxs} from "react/jsx-runtime";

/**
 * Using a vm to compile the mdx.  Why?  It seems like a way I can add
 * components accessible to the entry markdown file.  Is there a better way?
 *
 * This is the only way I could figure out how to _use_ the compiled module
 * without touching the filesystem.  Is a vfile a better choice?  I haven't
 * used them yet.
 */
import {NodeVM} from 'vm2';

/**
 * Load and compile the ./example.mdx file.  For reasons I don't quite
 * understand, I have to remove any import statements and the default
 * export.  If I don't do this, it throws an error (this could be a VM
 * issue and a reason not to use it).
 */
let compiled = String(await compile(await fs.readFile('example.mdx')))
  .replace(/import .*;/, '')
  .replace(/export default MDXContent;/, '')
;

/**
 * Here, grab the named export from the module.
 */
let namedExport = compiled.match(/export const (\w+)/);
if (namedExport) {
  namedExport = namedExport[1];
}

// Get the compiled version and remove the `export const`
compiled = compiled.replace(/export const (\w+)/, "$1");

/**
 * The compild version of this module needs to export MDXContent and the
 * named export (if there is one). We do that here.
 */
compiled += `
module.exports = {
  MDXContent,
  ${namedExport || "_void: ''"},
}
`;

/**
 * Set up our NodeVM.
 */
const vm = new NodeVM({
  console: 'inherit',
  sandbox: {
    // React resources needed by the module.
    _Fragment,
    _jsx,
    _jsxs,
  },
  require: {
    external : true,
    builtin  : ['fs','path'],
    root     : './',
    external : true,
    mock: {},
  },
});

// Now we've got a component.
let component = vm.run(compiled);

/**
 * For reasons I don't understand, when I render this I get empty HTML
 * comments. This removes them.
 */
console.log(
  renderToString(component.MDXContent())
  .replace(/<!-- -->/igsm,'')
);
```

And here's my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "mdx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdx-js/loader": "^2.3.0",
    "@mdx-js/mdx": "^2.3.0",
    "@mdx-js/node-loader": "^2.3.0",
    "@mdx-js/react": "^2.3.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-jsx": "^1.0.0",
    "vm2": "^3.9.17"
  }
}
```

This works-- but feels way too hacky. Since we're using unified under the hood, surely I can just render to static HTML?  From what I understand, MDX2 (via `@mdx-js/mdx`) basically does something like:

mdx → hast → esast

to get from MDX2 to a compiled component.  I understand that the `esast` step is to resolve imports and such.  I feel like I *should* be able to go from there *back* to `hast` and just render the fragment, but I don't *quite* get it.

### Next steps ...?

I would love to take a set of MDX2 (and maybe MD) *strings* and compile everything into a fragment *without accessing the disk*.  I saw [mdx-bundler](https://github.com/kentcdodds/mdx-bundler) (linked from [here in the mdx docs](https://mdxjs.com/guides/mdx-on-demand/)), but I couldn't get it to work.  It looks promising, though.

Here's an example of what I would like to get working:

**ComponentA**

```markdown
Component A says: {props.data}
```

**ComponentB**

```markdown
<ul>{props.items.map(item => (<li>{item}</li>))}</ul>
```

**entrypoint markdown**

```markdown
# Entrypoint

<ComponentA data="foo"/>
<ComponentB items={1,2,3}/>
```

Output:

```html
<h1>Entrypoint</h1>

<p>Component A says: foo</p>
<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></ul>
```

With some javascript that looks something like:

```js
...
const ComponentA = 'Component A says: {foo}';
const ComponentB = componentBFromSomewhere;
const entrypoint = entrypointFromSomewhere;

function mdxToHtml (e, opt) {
  // ... magic!
}

console.log(mdxToHtml(entrypoint, {components: {ComponentA, ComponentB}}));
```

Or something like that.  Help?

Comment: Very much late, but I think looking into Vite's import.meta.glob might be worth looking in to. I'm not sure how to run the function as something standalone, but it seems to parse the mdx and respond with an object that gives an html representation of the mdx (and markdown for that matter). I learned this by messing around with Astro.glob. If you get anywhere with this, I'm very much interested.